# Can't access any shares using a UNC

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows

I'm getting network error 0x80070002 The System cannot find the file specified when trying to open a network share on domain controller via Run \servername or IP. And the users using Folder Redirection can see their Desktop but no save anything on it, and IE favorites missing (but they are on the server).
Mapped network drives works also fine.

net view \servername shows shares and I can create new networks drives with net use without any problems.

It's only on some of my servers (2008 R2) not all for them, can't seem to find any difference on them.

I have tried:
sfc /scannow - Witch found some errors, but still same error after reboot.
Reinstalled Client for Microsoft Networks on NIC - Still same.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this is strange...

Long time ago I played around with http://www.askvg.com/how-to-remove-network-from-windows-7-explorers-navigation-pane/ to hide the Network from Navigation pane. Made a GPO to do this automatic. Yesterday I've moved that setting to it's own GPO.

Changed the reg setting back and it worked.

Comment: Also answered here: http://superuser.com/questions/323598/windows-7-unable-to-browse-to-network-shares-in-explorer-but-map-network-driv